# Aggregate latest values of documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have items that over the time can go from one category to the other.

Each change results in a new document with current state of the item.

I'm tying to get run basic analytics based on the latest state of the item like how many of them are in certain category or sum of values.

Basically I'm trying to collapse and aggregate results. But that's not possible.

Using PPL it's super simple, but does not scale, say few million docs.

```
search source=test-stats
| sort -timestamp
| dedup 1 id
| stats sum(value) as sum_value, COUNT(id) by category
```

My test docs:

```
{"_id": "doc-1-1", "id": "doc-1", "category": "c1", "value": 1010.0, "timestamp": "2023-07-07T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"_id": "doc-1-2", "id": "doc-1", "category": "c1", "value": 1012.0, "timestamp": "2023-07-08T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"_id": "doc-1-3", "id": "doc-1", "category": "c2", "value": 1013.0, "timestamp": "2023-07-09T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"_id": "doc-2-1", "id": "doc-2", "category": "c2", "value": 1021.0, "timestamp": "2023-07-07T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"_id": "doc-2-2", "id": "doc-2", "category": "c3", "value": 1022.0, "timestamp": "2023-07-10T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"_id": "doc-2-3", "id": "doc-2", "category": "c4", "value": 1023.0, "timestamp": "2023-07-11T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"_id": "doc-3-1", "id": "doc-3", "category": "c2", "value": 1031.0, "timestamp": "2023-07-07T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"_id": "doc-3-2", "id": "doc-3", "category": "c2", "value": 1032.0, "timestamp": "2023-07-10T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"_id": "doc-3-3", "id": "doc-3", "category": "c2", "value": 1033.0, "timestamp": "2023-07-11T00:00:00.000Z"}
```

Expected result would be:

```
sum_value  COUNT(id)  category
1023       1          c4
2046       2          c2
```

Comment: expected result is a bit complicated for me. Can you please explain how come `c2` category sum_value can be 2046? and why the **COUNT(id)** is 2 ?

Comment: Sure @MusabDogan `c2` is a "final/latest" state for ids `doc-1` (`doc-1-3`) and `doc-3` (`doc-3-3`), so we have count of 2 and `1013 + 1033`. `doc-2` is not taken into account since it's final state is `c4` (`doc-2-3`). Latest state if defined by `timestamp` field